# Nginx : Replace GET parameter with rules

Tags: nginx, replace, get, fixed

Looking for strongly  replacement GET parameter with fixed value

something like :

http://domain.com/index.php?alfa=1&beta=2&**debug=true**

to

http://domain.com/index.php?alfa=1&beta=2&**debug=false**

may be

```
if ($args ~ "debug=true") {
set  $args_debug false;
return 301 $uri;
}
```

but not work

Answer (score 2):

You can analyse the entire query string and capture the elements before and after the token you wish to modify. So that you can construct a new URI with the other elements intact:

```
if ($args ~ ^(.*)\bdebug=true\b(.*)$) { 
    return 301 $uri?$1debug=false$2;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of the `if` directive. However, the example given here is safe.

Comment: condition works , Thanks. Just need construct desintaion right URL . I am lost filename (( $1, $2 , $3 is empty